# Convert to uppercase with bit operators

Tags: c

Hi I have a function that converts characters to uppercase, but don't understand this line of code `*src & = ~0x20`.

Here is the complete code

```
void upper_case(char *src)
{
    while (*src != '\0')
    {
        if (islower(*src))
          *src &= ~0x20;
        src++;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would it use `islower()` but not `toupper()`...

Comment: Google "ASCII table".

Comment: @dreamlax -- It doesn't want to convert a blank to null.

Comment: Note: Per the C spec, if `*src` take on a value < 0 (aside from EOF), the result is undefined behavior.  Character handling functions like `islower()` in `<ctype.h>` are well defined for `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  But I have yet to come across an implementation that doesn't also define values -128 to -1 for most of these functions.  The most portable approach involves controlling the conversion of `*src` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: "a function that converts characters to uppercase"...The question would be: Which characters? Characters are members of one or more character sets. Characters sets have one or more encodings, which represent each character as a sequence of one or more bytes. The algorithm would work for ASCII but ASCII is quite rare except as a subset of a larger character set like Unicode or Windows-1252.

Comment: @HotLicks No, dreamlax's question is “if you are going to use the standard function `islower`, why don't you use the standard function `toupper` which comes from the same standard?”. The question is not what `islower` is for in the question's code.

Answer (score 4):

This is an ASCII solution to subtract 32 from a lowercase character's integral value, which equals the uppercase of it.

It doesn't work for all character sets/encodings. If your environment / locale is the "C" locale, or "En_US", this will work, otherwise it may not because not every character set has a relationship of 0x20 (32) between lower and uppercase, nor the concept of upper or lower case.

For that matter, even with ASCII, islower() isn't a safe check (which I see Ray Chen just pointed out in the comments) due to accent chars and other issues. I would instead use

```
if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')   // this == islower() in "C" locale, but not others
```

to limit the set to avoid accent chars. islower() doesn't guarantee that -32 will uppercase it.

In any case, it is "the old way" which, sadly, has gone the way of many other "simple" tricks and assumptions, like .txt meaning ASCII.

Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx for interesting reading.

Answer (score 1):

Lower case characters are in the range of 0x61 to 0x7a. Upper-case characters are in the range of 0x41 to 0x5a, exactly 0x20 less.

So you have two options: you can either subtract 0x20, or you can clear the 0x20 bit, which what it does: `~0x20` is the complement of 0x20 (i.e. 0xbf), and if you `and` it, it removes that bit.

Comment: Yes, but what about numbers. I know you are right but I don't think your answer explains that case.

Comment: It starts with an `islower` test, so the operation is only applied to lowercase letters, all others are left untouched.

Comment: Note that depending on the locale, `islower()` can return true for accented letters, and for those letters, the "subtract 0x20" trick does not work.